# Does total cross section in high energy physics only depend on s?

Tags: scattering-cross-section

I am very confused why people draw pictures of total cross section with respect to s.

For example

[image]

Does cross section only depends on s?

Can anyone explain this a bit, or provide any references?

Comment: It depends. It always depends. In my dissertation work the interesting Mandelstam variable was $t$, but we were also very interested in the electron energy loss (which we denoted $W$) which isn't a Mandelstam variable.

Comment: @dmckee But the total cross section should always only depend on s, right?